# Eclipse "Run On Hadoop" - no response

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to run a MapReduce program in a Ubuntu VM using Eclipse IDE installed on my Windows machine.

However, when I right-click on my program file and select the option **Run As->Run on Hadoop** nothing happens. Ideally, I should get a pop-up asking me to select a server where I want to run my program but that's not happening.

Can any one help me out?

Comment: What plug-in is this? Did you examine Eclipse logs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop 0.20.2 Eclipse plugin not fully functioning - can't 'Run on Hadoop'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883321/hadoop-0-20-2-eclipse-plugin-not-fully-functioning-cant-run-on-hadoop)